# Getting error "type=Method Not Allowed, status=405"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am able to get the response when using the POSTMAN but  not through code .

Here is what i am doing through POSTMAN

```
RequestMethod.POST
In HEADERS
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept    : */*

In BODY 
c_id : myname
c_secret : mypassword
g_type :  myvalue
c_scope : value2
```

This is how i am sending the request and i get the following response

```
{
    "access_token": "token_value",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 6000,
    "scope": "scope_vale",
    "jti": "jti_value"
}
```

In POSTMAN i also disabled SSL Verfication .

This is how i am coding in my SPRING BOOT Application

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/site")
public class CSController {



     final String url="url name";


       @RequestMapping(path = "/token", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<?> getToken() throws JsonProcessingException
        {

          RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();


            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList( MediaType.ALL) );
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);


            Map<String, String> bodyParamMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

          bodyParamMap.put("c_id", "myname");
          bodyParamMap.put("c_secret", "mypassword");
          bodyParamMap.put("g_type", "myvalue");
          bodyParamMap.put("c_scope", "value2");

          String reqBodyData = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(bodyParamMap);
          HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(reqBodyData, headers);

          System.out.println(  " get token from url 2");

          ResponseEntity<String> result =  rt.exchange(url,HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);



            return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
        }


}
```

But i am getting the below error

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jun 18 10:49:58 IST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your controller method supports `POST` requests not `GET`,so while sending a request to browser will result in `method Not allowed`

```
 @RequestMapping(path = "/token", method = RequestMethod.POST) // POST
            public ResponseEntity<?> getToken() throws JsonProcessingException
            {

              RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
```

> How to resolve

Remove explicit POST from your method and it will work for both GET AND POST requests

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/token") // Remove explicit mapping here
                public ResponseEntity<?> getToken() throws JsonProcessingException
                {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i got what was the problem .I did the same what you told but i got a new certificate error
`Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: 
I/O error on POST request for "https://url-for-token":`

Comment: ` sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; 
nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: In POSTMAN i also disabled SSL Verfication .

Comment: url you are using is not working,check for any firewall issue on server or see if you are passing correct url

Comment: URL is correct as i am able to get the response in POSTMAN. So what should i check next?

Comment: How you are passing the parameters in browser ??@OracleMonkey

Comment: not passing any parameter in the browser.There is no parameter .Only BODY and HEADER to be passed.See code